# how to hide button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i trying to create a scroll div with button click.

and i want to hide button if it was end of scroll, i mean if i can't scroll anymore then i want to hide the button. and show it when it can scroll.

here's what i tried

**Javascript:**

```js
   $('#right-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').animate({
        scrollLeft: "+=300px"
      }, "slow");
   });
   
     $('#left-button').click(function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').animate({
        scrollLeft: "-=300px"
      }, "slow");
 });
```

```css
.left{
 float: left; 
 width: 30%;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.internal{
 width: 31.75%;
 height: 100%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
}

.center{
 float: left; 
 width: 38.9%;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 1px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*will change this to hidden later to deny scolling to user*/
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.right{
 float: right; 
 width: 30%;
 height: 200px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left">
      <button id="left-button">
        swipe left
      </button>
    </div>
     <div class="center" id="content">
      <div class=internal>
        div 1
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 2
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 3
      </div>
       <div class=internal>
        div 4
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="right">
    <button id="right-button">
        swipe right
      </button>
    </div>
```

i found the good one here, but i dont know how to modify it.[codepen](https://codepen.io/mahish/pen/RajmQw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this, this is my final jquery based on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/mahish/pen/RajmQw) link

```
// duration of scroll animation
var scrollDuration = "slow";
// paddles
var leftPaddle = document.getElementsByClassName('left');
var rightPaddle = document.getElementsByClassName('right');
// get items dimensions
var itemsLength = $('.internal').length;
var itemSize = $('.internal').outerWidth(true);
// get some relevant size for the paddle triggering point
var paddleMargin = 20;

// get wrapper width
var getMenuWrapperSize = function() {
    return $('.center').outerWidth();
}
var menuWrapperSize = getMenuWrapperSize();
// the wrapper is responsive
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    menuWrapperSize = getMenuWrapperSize();
});
// size of the visible part of the menu is equal as the wrapper size 
var menuVisibleSize = menuWrapperSize;

// get total width of all menu items
var getMenuSize = function() {
    return itemsLength * itemSize;
};
var menuSize = getMenuSize();
// get how much of menu is invisible
var menuInvisibleSize = menuSize - menuWrapperSize;

// get how much have we scrolled to the left
var getMenuPosition = function() {
    return $('.center').scrollLeft();
};

// finally, what happens when we are actually scrolling the menu
$('.center').on('scroll', function() {

    // get how much of menu is invisible
    menuInvisibleSize = menuSize - menuWrapperSize;
    // get how much have we scrolled so far
    var menuPosition = getMenuPosition();

    var menuEndOffset = menuInvisibleSize - paddleMargin;

    // show & hide the paddles 
    // depending on scroll position
    if (menuPosition <= paddleMargin) {
        $(leftPaddle).addClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (menuPosition < menuEndOffset) {
        // show both paddles in the middle
        $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
    } else if (menuPosition >= menuEndOffset) {
        $(leftPaddle).removeClass('hidden');
        $(rightPaddle).addClass('hidden');
}

    // print important values
    $('#print-wrapper-size span').text(menuWrapperSize);
    $('#print-menu-size span').text(menuSize);
    $('#print-menu-invisible-size span').text(menuInvisibleSize);
    $('#print-menu-position span').text(menuPosition);

});

// scroll to left
$(rightPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.center').animate( { scrollLeft: "+=400px"}, scrollDuration);
});

// scroll to right
$(leftPaddle).on('click', function() {
    $('.center').animate( { scrollLeft: "-=400" }, scrollDuration);
});
```

Comment: Looks a bit complex , But okay

Answer (score 0):

Seems like all you need to do is to add a hide or show control to your click events.

add to the right click event

```
  $('#right-button').hide();
  $('#left-button').show();
```

add to the left click event

```
  $('#right-button').show();
  $('#left-button').hide();
```

and then set the default behavior when page loads to show the button starting status, such as

```
  $('#left-button').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You lack specifics regarding which button you are trying to hide and which direction you are trying to scroll. This answer is assuming you want to hide '#right-button' and you are scrolling vertical.

This will create an event listener for scrolling, when you scroll and you reach the bottom of the page (you will need to determine what that is) it will hide the right-button otherwise it will show it.

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === 5158){
//  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() === buttomOfPage){
        $('#right-button').hide()
    } else {
        $('#right-button').show()
    }
})
```